# document-set filters?

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, document-set

I have a library with multiple document sets, each of which has custom metadata. I want to create a filter for use within doc-set A that filters on A's custom metadata, and a filter for use within doc-set B that filters on B's unique metadata, etc.

So far I see how to create a filter at the library level but not at the doc-set level. This is a problem because B's metadata displays in the filter panel even when in A. How do I create filters unique to each doc set?

Answer (score 1):

Filter is used at library level, there is no direct way to set a filter just at document set level.

As a workaround, you can create different custom document set content types and add them into your library, then create Doc-Set A and Doc-Set B using different content type.

Then create a view at library level with a filter by A, and same steps to create a view with a filter by B.

Then go to the document set content type used to create doc-set A, then set its Welcome page view to the view which is filtered by A, like the below:
[image]

Similar setting for doc-set B.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that modern document sets would have filters, but I guess not. Thanks for the workaround suggestions-- I'll give it a try.

Comment: Please have a try and if my reply helps you, please remember to accept it as answer. :)

Comment: From what I can tell, a filter created via a View is a static filter, not the dynamic type of filter created in Metadata Navigation. Is that correct? The dynamic type (I think of it as an Amazon-style filter) is what I'm looking for. Am I misunderstanding?